# My code worked completely until I used ScreenManger in my .kv file

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to make a login page for my app. For this, I am using kivymd.I was expecting to get the user input printed through my terminal and it did too until I separated my screens using screen manager.

For the purpose I used the on_release with the button in my .kv and called the function. But it gives the following error:

```
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'usernamecreate'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
   File "C:/Users/SAMSUNG/PycharmProjects/SchoolApp/main.py", line 51, in create
     print(self.root.ids.usernamecreate.text)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I have provided only the beginning and ending lines of the error since the whole was really long.

This is my .kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    CreateAccountScreen:

<LoginScreen>:
    name:'login'
    MDTextField:
        id:username
        hint_text:'Email or Phone number'
        helper_text:'Username cannot be left empty'
        required:True
        helper_text_mode:'on_error'
        icon_right_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
    MDTextField:
        id:password
        hint_text:'Enter Password'
        helper_text:'Password cannot be left empty'
        required:True
        helper_text_mode:'on_error'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
        password:True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Login'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x:None
    MDLabel:
        text:'-------------OR---------------'
        pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.3}
        halign:'center'
    MDFlatButton:
        text:'Create New Account'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        size_hint_x:None
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'caccount'

<CreateAccountScreen>:
    name:'caccount'
    MDTextField:
        id:usernamecreate
        hint_text:'Email or Phone number'
        helper_text:'Username cannot be left empty'
        required:True
        helper_text_mode:'on_error'
        icon_right_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
    MDTextField:
        id:password
        hint_text:'Enter Password'
        helper_text:'Password cannot be left empty'
        required:True
        helper_text_mode:'on_error'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.6}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
        password:True
    MDTextField:
        id:password1
        hint_text:'Confirm Password'
        helper_text:'Password cannot be left empty'
        required:True
        helper_text_mode:'on_error'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:300
        password:True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Create Account'

        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        size_hint_x:None
        on_release:app.create()
    MDLabel:
        text:'-------------OR---------------'
        pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.3}
        halign:'center'
    MDFlatButton:
        text:'Login'
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
        size_hint_x:None
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'login'
        **#Here I have called the function**
```

I dont think calling the function gives error, but see what happens inside the function:

```
class SchoolApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        return
    def create(self):
        print(self.root.ids.usernamecreate.text)
        print(self.root.ids.password.text)
```

Please suggest what I can do to remove the error as everything elese is working fine I did not put the whole code. But please tell me to do so if you want to see it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `create` function like below to solve the issue:

```
    def create(self):
        print(self.root.children[0].ids.usernamecreate.text)
        print(self.root.children[0].ids.password.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the use of that .children[0] please explain.

Comment: Here ```self.root``` is the ```WindowManager``` object and it has the children ```screen```. So to access the ids of the current screen you need to cast ```self.root.children[0]```.